# Unknown set bags - long yellow plate, lots of brown

Tags: set-identification

I have 2 bags that are not opened and I am unsure what set they are from, they could be the same set but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Bag 1 looks to have an orange wing and a purple disc in the bag.
- Bag 5 looks to have a wheel axel and a 16x2 long yellow piece.

[image: Image of bags]

Comment: I agree with @IvanSanchez - it looks like both bags have been re-made: In bag 1 that rudder/tail element has had it's sticker applied, but the bag it's in contains a number of parts that aren't in the [one set that combination came from](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75176-1). Similarly, bag 5 appears to contain a Dark Blue Slope, Inverted 45 6 x 4 Double with 4 x 4 Cutout, which also [only appeared in one set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8633-1), but again, with many extra parts that don't appear in that set.

Comment: To add to the evidence that these are resealed bags with random, used parts: Bag 5 contains a wheel base with a wheel hub already connected to it. Those  would never be packed like that by LEGO.

Answer (score 6):

In the bag marked "5" I can peek:

- A "©2017" mark.
- A [yellow 2x16 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4282&colorID=3&in=A).
- A [dark blue 6x4 double inverted slope](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60219&colorID=63&in=A).

There are no (known) sets containing both those bricks.

The bag marked "1" has a [dark orange tail shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6239&colorID=68&in=A) **with sticker applied** (making it [6239pb067](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6239pb067)). Note that [there exists a sticker sheet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=75176stk01) for [the only set featuring that tail part](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75176-1).

My guess therefore is: those bags have been opened before, filled with parts from several sets, and possibly have been resealed.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ali If the answer has helped you, please mark it with a check to indicate that no further answers are required. Thanks!